# Calling an artisan command from a queue job is executed endlessly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-artisan

I have what seemed simple: a queued job that calls a custom artisan command using `Artisan::call()`.

What I test the command myself in CLI, it works perfectly fine and do it's job entirely. However, when it's called from the job, it starts, do part of it's job and seemingly just... Hangs and stay in limbo, waiting for something.

Is there anyway to call the command from a job and tell the queued job not to wait for it?

Comment: "it starts, do part of it's job." Does it stall at the same spot everytime?

Comment: Hard to tell with 100% certainty because there is no error thrown anywhere, but I'll say yes anyway. At some point in the command I start a task with Symfony Process, the task itself goes on for the amount of time it is supposed to (and ends, I inspected the process in the OS to make sure of it), but everything after just won't execute while in the job. I've even seen the job getting refired after a bit of time.

Comment: Are you processing large files or making requests that respond with a lot of data?

Comment: I'm recording an audio stream. It does not return anything big, only the program output, the stream is saved on disk by the program called.

Comment: Interesting, that isn't something I've personally ever done in a job, are you closing the file when the stream is complete? I could see an open file handler or something of the sort holding up a job.

Comment: From what I understand, Symfony Process closes it when it catches the exit code from OS.